# Можно ли сейчас использовать ODATA с .NET CORE 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте, кто нибудь знает, на сегодняшний момент можно ли как нибудь прикрутить ODATA к .NET CORE 2
Я находил на GITHUB несколько репозиториев, но там нет инструкций и вообщем я не смог разобраться. Буду рад если кто нибудь выложит туториал.

Вот к примеру:

1. https://github.com/joshcomley/Microsoft.AspNetCore...
2. https://github.com/jonathanburrows/odata
3. https://github.com/SoaringCalifornia/ODataCore